# How can I update and load different div blocks via AJAX based on a boolean variable on PHP side?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two divs on a page, one for a form and one for output of the form.

When I submit the form, if the form is *not* valid, I want to redisplay the form and highlight errors in the form.  If the form is valid, hide the form div, and show processed output.

I can determine whether or not form is valid inside my PHP, i.e. `$isFormValid = true;`

If need be, I can also reload the form, when it was valid into the form div.  (As I have to reload it when it is not valid).

**Question**

How?

To clarify here is the flow of events I wish to have:

[image]

Comment: For valid form submission what's the server output format? HTML? JSON?

Comment: At the moment I am using HTML, but it is flexible.  Form data is basically whatever is in `$_POST`, and I can take it and do whatever with it.  Currently wrapping it into HTML, which is probably due to legacy reasons is easier to keep as HTML....

Comment: to add, the form itself is generated via `Zend\Form` library, which produces HTML, so that part has to stay HTML....

Comment: One thing I could do perhaps is load both form and output divs at all times (as a one contiguous block), and then hide/show one of them based on the PHP variable....

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP file:

```
$validFormOutputInJSONFormat = '...';
$invalidFormValidationMessagesInJSONFormat = '...';

header('Content-type: application/json'); // Remove this line if you've already set this http header in your code.

if ($isFormValid) {
    echo '{"valid":true, "data":'.$validFormOutputInJSONFormat.'}';
} else {
    echo '{"valid":false, "data":'.$invalidFormValidationMessagesInJSONFormat.'}';
}
```

In your ajax response handling function use something like this:

```
if (responseData.valid) {
    // JS code to hide the form
    // JS code to show output. responseData.data has the info you will need here
} else {
    // JS code to show validation messages in the form. responseData.data has the info you will need here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can output your result as json from your serverside code, something like

```
{success:true, formValid:true , message: 'success result'}
```

or

```
{success:true, formValid: false, message: 'some error message'}
```

then you can use ajax post method to post your form, and in success, you can check the formValid value and hide/show divs or error messages depending on formValid value

```
  $('#myform').on('submit' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      data : $(this).serializeArray(),
      url : $(this).attr('action'),
      type : 'POST',
      success : function(result){
        if(result.success) {
           if(result.formValid === true) {
             // form validation passed.
           }
           else {
             // form is invalid. 
           }
        }else{
           // ajax didn't worked out, no response
        }
      }

    })
  })
```